# How can I create a custom play-pause button for a videojs controlbar in Nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, video.js

I am using Nextjs,I want to custom button play pause in controlbar in videojs, but what I have tried so far isn't working:

```js
if (!playerRef.current) {
  // The Video.js player needs to be _inside_ the component el for React 18 Strict Mode.
  const videoElement = document.createElement("video-js");
  videoElement.classList.add("vjs-big-play-centered");
  videoRef.current.appendChild(videoElement);

  const player = (playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
    player.currentTime();
    handlePlayerReady(player);
  }));

  // You could update an existing player in the `else` block here
  // on prop change, for example:
} else {
  const player = playerRef.current;
  player.autoplay(options.autoplay);
  player.src(options.sources);
  player.currentTime(options.currentTime);
  player.volume(options.volume);
  player.playbackRate(options.playbackRate);
}
```